# Virtual COM Port Frame Error Treatment on Windows [FTDI]

Tags: windows, com, ftdi

I have a virtual COM port on Windows from Future Technologies (usb converter) which works fine but has a funny cravat with frame errors. When I pull the receive line low for a long time on the device, I get 0x00 showing up any terminal program I use on windows. I do not get a frame error. I only get a frame error if the data content is something other than all low signals. Can someone confirm whether or not this is intended behavior for windows COM ports or FTDI devices? I loop through sending all byte values 0-255 with my function generator and every one creates an error where no stop bit is found besides 0 (line pulled low indefinitely). On a micro controller I am developing with, all frame errors are reported. Is windows/my driver suppressing the frame error for all 0 values?

Comment: walloftextishardtoread. & what's a funny cravat, other than a comedy neck-tie?